# Como receber um titulo(title) de uma imagem para o valor de uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Estava tentando fazer desse modo:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Depois que eu imprimo essa imagem, não funciona, ele imprime `[object HTMLCollection]`.

Comment: [Assim talvéz?](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/62f9ajgr/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) retorna uma [coleção de elementos DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Você tem que acessar, nessa coleção, o elemento desejado e então seu atributo `title`:

```
// Por ex, pegando o título da primeira imagem
imagens[0].title
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skqp3b2q/)**</kbd>

Dessa forma, ao contrário da resposta aceita, você pode iterar sobre a coleção:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
}
```

Porém para acessar apenas uma imagem, a resposta aceita é a mais correta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter o titulo (`title`) pelo tanto pelo id (`ID`), tal como pelo name (`NAME`) da imagem, assim evitando erro caso haja varias imagens no script, ou inclusão de imagens acima desta. O que mudaria caso usa-se `imagens[0].title;`
Pois o **`[0]` indica que é a primeira**.

defina um id na imagem.
Ex.: `<img src="imagem.jpg" id="imagem1" title="Meu titulo"/>`

Script

```
var ConteudoTitulo = document.getElementById('imagem1').getAttribute("title");
```

***Desta forma, mesmo que acrescente novas imagens e/ou altere as posições, não precisará modificar o script.***

A seguir um modelo do código para visualizar como funciona:
https://jsfiddle.net/cp1dchds/

Para utilizar em navegadores antigos, o recomendado seria usar o metodo nativo:

```
var ConteudoTitulo = document.getElementById('imagem1').title;
```

Comment: **Importante!** Ao declarar document.getElementsByTagName('img'), sem um método na frente, ele retorna o objeto, por essa razão exibe [object HTMLCollection], pois possui mais de uma IMG. Mesmo havendo apenas uma imagem, necessita sempre definir o método. Cada objeto possui tipos de métodos compatíveis. Apenas recomendo utilizar por name (getElementsByName) ou tag name (getElementsByTagName) caso seja sequencial, pois alterar a ordem de um elemento pode modificar o resultado em alguns casos.